# "Type 'manage.py help ' for help on a specific subcommand" - Error solving python with IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, handler, uvicorn

I'm trying to run a django project with IIS on Windows server, I've already modified handler mapings and FastCGI Settings -> [image status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAMdi.png)It should be running at this point. There's any error but the page is not running. (even withouth /manage.py is the same legend)

Legend: "Type 'manage.py help ' for help on a specific subcommand. Available subcommands: [auth]changepasswordcreatesuperuser [channels]runworker [contenttypes]remove_stale_contenttypes [django]checkcompilemessagescreatecachetabledbshelldiffsettingsdumpdataflushinspectdbloaddatamakemessagesmakemigrationsmigratesendtestemailshellshowmigrationssqlflushsqlmigratesqlsequenceresetsquashmigrationsstartappstartprojecttesttestserver [sessions]clearsessions [staticfiles]collectstaticfindstaticrunserver "

[Here's the image with the default document config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VdXD.png)

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: What is `manage.py`, and why should we expect to be able to use it in this way?

Comment: Did you navigate to that page, or were you redirected there?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's a Django script used for internal management.

Comment: I expect @KarlKnechtel knows this, @Carcigenicate , which is why the question comes up.  Look at the image.  The html *path* says `/manage.py` as part of the web path.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @R.Uziel It's worded as a legitimate question, which is why I mentioned it. And yes, the server is running the manage script and serving the results for some reason. I was wondering if they navigated there, or if they were redirected there, since the latter may hint at a specific configuration problem.

Comment: My apologies @Carcigenicate .  It is absolutely a legitimate question.  I just meant your second comment.  I believe that @KarlKnechtel understood what the command `manage.py` was, that's all.  Hopefully the OP will answer your question.  Apologies if I was misunderstood.

Comment: I don't know about Django, beyond "it's a Python web framework" and having occasionally seen a bit of code. I do know that that text looks like a usage message intended for a command line program, not for web interaction.

Comment: I posted the image with /manage.py because the legend is exactly the same if I just search with http://localhost:87/ (never redirect me to http://localhost:87/manage.py)
And manage.py is my main, so that's why I searched URL with manage.py

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.